# Unable to get property 'test' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ES6 with React and references don't seem to be playing ball.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  test() {
    console.log(React.refs.test);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pure-g">
        <Nav>
          <NavButton onClick={this.test}>Test</NavButton>
        </Nav>
        <Map lat="53.15" lng="-0.5" zoom="9" />
        <SearchMenu ref="test" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Am I using refs incorrectly?

On another note, suddenly my onClick event is occurring when the page loads. Here's my button component.

```
export default class NavButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="pure-menu-item" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <a className="pure-menu-link">{this.props.children}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/33537/

Answer (score 2):

The refs are available on the component instance, not statically on `React` itself. Your ref should be referenced by `this.refs.test` rather than `React.refs.test`. This presents another issue with your example - the click event callback won't be invoked with the right context. You could work around that by binding the function passed through to button component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  test() {
    console.log(this.refs.test);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pure-g">
        <Nav>
          <NavButton onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>Test</NavButton>
        </Nav>
        <Map lat="53.15" lng="-0.5" zoom="9" />
        <SearchMenu ref="test" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<NavButton />` to this

`<NavButton onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>Test</NavButton>`

Now `this` in your test function will be the component.

```
test() {
  console.log(this); //this will be your App Component
}
```

As for why your click is triggering on load I'd make sure you aren't actually calling the onClick function by accident:

`this.props.onClick()` instead of `this.props.onClick`

Comment: is there anyway to shorthand this.test.bind(this)? es6 seems overly complicated for no reason, are there actually any benefits except for the es6 features?

Comment: @Jacob Mason you can you arrow function `onClick={() => this.test() }`

Comment: or you can use class properties `test = () => { ... }` which is currently under scrutiny for ES2017, but Babel has a transform already in place which works well. This answer does not solve the problem though, which is actually the incorrect implementation of `React.refs`